# PostgreSQL- Full Text Search limitations (~, ~*, LIKE)

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, sql-like, text-search

Hi there! I've been asked to explain some limitations that could have the operators (~, ~*, LIKE) when doing Full text limitation.

I've seen some things but nothing really relevant.

Could someone point out 2 or 3 limitations they have faced when using this operators for text search in PostgreSQL?

Many thanks!!

Comment: `LIKE` doesn't allow for handy things that POSIX regex has such as non-capturing groups, start/end string anchors `^` or `$`, and more. `LIKE` misses on a lot of the finer regex control that `~` and `~*` offer. Additionally, regardless of using `LIKE` or the POSIX operators, if you start your comparison string with a wildcard (`%` or `.*` for example), it ignores indexes on the field being matched. Check out this documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-matching.html

Comment: You're welcome! As a bonus, this is an amazing resource but if you're interested on further reading on how pattern matching affects indexes, check this out: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning

Comment: Your question is unclear. What limitation? Full text search is about finding whole words in natural language texts, not about pattern matching.